# Invalid YAML Symfony4

Tags: symfony4

am currently on symfony4 and I have this error

[image: error]

my routes

```html
 property.show:
  path: /biens/{slug}-{id}
  controller: App\Controller\PropertyController::show
  requirements:
    id: "\d+"
    slug: "[a-z0-9\-]*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex escaping isn't right, try this:

```
property.show: 
  controller: "App\\Controller\\PropertyController::show"
  path: "/biens/{slug}-{id}"
  requirements: 
    id: \d+
    slug: "[a-z0-9\\-]*"
```